# QAudioInput::notify() isn't executed while capturing sound from mic

Tags: c++, qt, audio, audio-recording

I want to use `QAudioInput` to capture sound from mic, process it and then play. As I understood, I need to connect to `notify` signal and inside handler for it user `readAll()` function to get raw data. But the problem is, this handler function is never executed. Here is my code:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{

    QList<QAudioDeviceInfo> list = QAudioDeviceInfo::availableDevices(QAudio::AudioInput);

    if(list.isEmpty())
    {
        qDebug() << "No audio input device";
        return;
    }

    QAudioDeviceInfo info = QAudioDeviceInfo::defaultInputDevice();

    QAudioFormat format;
    // Set up the desired format, for example:
    format.setSampleRate(44100);
    format.setChannelCount(1);
    format.setSampleSize(32);
    format.setCodec("audio/pcm");
    format.setByteOrder(QAudioFormat::LittleEndian);
    format.setSampleType(QAudioFormat::UnSignedInt);

    if (!info.isFormatSupported(format)) {
        qWarning() << "Default format not supported, trying to use the nearest.";
        format = info.nearestFormat(format);
    }

    qDebug() << "input device :" << info.deviceName();

    audio = new QAudioInput(info, format);
    qDebug("created()");

    connect(audio, SIGNAL(notify()), this, SLOT(onNotify()));
    audio->setNotifyInterval(10);

    bufferInput = audio->start();
}

void MainWindow::onNotify()
{
    qDebug() << "onNotify()";
    //QByteArray array = bufferInput->readAll();
    //bufferOutput->write(array);
}
```

(`audio` is of type `QAudioInput*` and `bufferInput` is of type `QIODevice*`)

and when I click the button, "input device = " and "created()" messages are displayed, but "onNotify()" isn't shown.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It might be that the audio input device on your computer doesn't support the QAudioFormat you are asking it to play, and therefore isn't starting.  I suggest connecting the QAudioInput's stateChanged(QAudio::State) signal to a slot and having that slot print out the new state value, so you can get some better insight into what is (or isn't) happening to the device.

Comment: added handler to the stateChanged signal that does something like that: `qDebug() << newState; qDebug() << (audio->error());`, and all it shows is "IdleState
NoError"

Comment: Strange thing, changing `bufferInput = audio->start();` to `bufferInput = new QBuffer(); bufferInput->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);audio->start(bufferInput);` made it work, but I still don't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

`QAudioInput` seems quite broken. Or I'm utterly misunderstanding something.

The only thing that worked reliably for me was to use the `readyRead()` signal of the `QIODevice` buffer returned by `start()`. Unfortunately, that isn't fired very often on my system (around every 40 to 60ms on my system).

---

What I've found is that `notify()` starts firing when I either call `resume()` on the `QAudioInput` (because it's in idle state after calling `start()`) or do a `readAll()` on the `QIODevice` (!). But at least with PyQt this leads to a stack overflow after a minute or so.

I would suspect the platform matters as well, as the actual QAudioInput implementation depends on the platform and audio system used (PulseAudio on Fedora 32 in my case).

Answer (score 0):

Connecting a slot to readyRead signal of QAudioInput and reading from QIODevice with readAll is the correct solution. Why do you think 40 or 60 ms interval is inappropriate? QAudioInput object must capture some audio during this interval and send signal after it.